# jQuery closest() in .this element is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a embeded iframe text element in 3 modal elemets and each has a Copy button. When I click on one copy button, I need to get the output of the particular iframe text. If I use

`$(".embed-iframe-text").text();`

It will output all the three iframe texts together. To avoid that and get the particular iframe text, I used

```
$(this).closest(".embed-iframe-text").text();
```

but can't get the output. What is the wrong here?

```js
$(".copy-iframe").on("click", function() {
 var m = $(".embed-iframe-text").text();
        var n = $(this).closest(".embed-iframe-text").text();
 alert(n);
 });
```

```css
.embed-iframe-text, .embed-src span {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- modal 1 -->
<div class="modal-body">
 <div class="embed-iframe">
  <span class="embed-iframe-text">
   &lt;iframe width="100" height="100" src="" frameborder="" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;
  </span>
 </div>
 <div class="embed-button">
  <div class="embed-src">
   <span>Dynamic text here</span>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary copy-iframe">Copy</button>
 </div>
</div>

<!-- modal 2 -->
<div class="modal-body">
 <div class="embed-iframe">
  <span class="embed-iframe-text">
   &lt;iframe width="200" height="200" src="" frameborder="" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;
  </span>
 </div>
 <div class="embed-button">
  <div class="embed-src">
   <span>Dynamic text here</span>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary copy-iframe">Copy</button>
 </div>
</div>

<!-- modal 3 -->
<div class="modal-body">
 <div class="embed-iframe">
  <span class="embed-iframe-text">
   &lt;iframe width="300" height="300" src="" frameborder="" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;
  </span>
 </div>
 <div class="embed-button">
  <div class="embed-src">
   <span>Dynamic text here</span>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary copy-iframe">Copy</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var n = $(this).closest(".embed-iframe-text").text();
```

this won't work as it doesn't comes on the same level, you need to go to the parent and find the item inside it.

use `.parents('.modal-body').find(".embed-iframe-text")`

```js
$(".copy-iframe").on("click", function() {
  var m = $(".embed-iframe-text").text();
  var n = $(this).parents('.modal-body').find(".embed-iframe-text").text();
  console.log(n)
});
```

```css
.embed-iframe-text,
.embed-src span {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- modal 1 -->
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="embed-iframe">
    <span class="embed-iframe-text">
   &lt;iframe1 width="100" height="100" src="" frameborder="" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;
  </span>
  </div>
  <div class="embed-button">
    <div class="embed-src">
      <span>Dynamic text here</span>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary copy-iframe">Copy</button>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- modal 2 -->
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="embed-iframe">
    <span class="embed-iframe-text">
   &lt;iframe2 width="200" height="200" src="" frameborder="" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;
  </span>
  </div>
  <div class="embed-button">
    <div class="embed-src">
      <span>Dynamic text here</span>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary copy-iframe">Copy</button>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- modal 3 -->
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="embed-iframe">
    <span class="embed-iframe-text">
   &lt;iframe3 width="300" height="300" src="" frameborder="" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;
  </span>
  </div>
  <div class="embed-button">
    <div class="embed-src">
      <span>Dynamic text here</span>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary copy-iframe">Copy</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I just realized from the comment that or `.closest('.modal-body').find(".embed-iframe-text")` would work too. this will find the parent modal-body first and then the child.

Comment: :-) have a nice day +1

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef thank you for your comment, didn't thought of that.